# How to read and translate a filename.z.json file

Tags: json, file, compression

My file has a `.z.json`-extension and can be found [here](https://livetiming.formula1.com/static/2023/2023-05-28_Monaco_Grand_Prix/2023-05-28_Race/Position.z.json).

The content of the file is

```
"7ZQ7a8MwFIX/i2Yn3IekK3nv3EIztCkdQslgSpySuFPwf6+USMZZbiGzFyODPs7RuY+LeTmeu6E79qb9uJhNd9ifh93hx7SGgHgFbkVhg7Z10kJcB+YAIFvTmKd+OHX7s2kvBvPnddgNv+nXPPeb0+7rO115M+1KPGFj3vMJbTptTeuAx8aQAnkrcIMi51OGMENWg4TjDQrRuwJRghBUqTBJoZ9T2qu8g6IVyVOhJFOaw5QF1SwYZlmg18OoWkw4dxgUipArVJSszalrWQgGW/yJDUUJM6VmIVCoCBhmxSK1xN75SoU7inWt0k1RarXoSqmdYf2UYOCi5TMlao1j1UKZ584P9bvVHbrq8NpZk0PnVIdUe5dcHROXKK9nyK7Oyd1wiZqG5ykNmlNBn5PaUSnDML1rHJt/dg3CGoTFW1p2zbJrll2z7JrHd83n+Ac="
```

Apparently, the most common type of file that contains the `.z`-file extension is compressed Unix files.
How do I translate / uncompress this file to its human-understandable version? I have no additional information.

Comment: What language?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Base-64 encoded raw deflate data. You need to decode the Base-64 to binary, and then use zlib to inflate it. The result is 2278 bytes of json.

Comment: Cool - I shall delete my answer.